# Remove Default round border of <select> element in Mac OS Browser:Chrome

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

in 'select' element i haven't added border property in CSS of it , and also i have added following CSS in it

```
    .select
     {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
     }
```

though its showing me round border in Chrome (Mac OS),why it is so ,how can i get over it ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can update css [`appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance) property.

```
.select{ 
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;   
   -webkit-border-radius: 0;  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */    
   -moz-border-radius: 0;  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */     
   border-radius: 0;  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
}
```

Comment: Please notice, that the arrows disappear, too. And without the arrows it's hard to recognize the element as a select field.

Comment: @BjörnWeinbrenner you can use a custom arrow as a background-image, it works for me :)

Answer (score 4):

Though its a old question. I tried by keeping arrow on the right side.

```
select {
    color: #fff;
    background: #17406B;
    border: solid 7px #17406B;
    outline: #17406B solid thick;
    outline-offset: -5px;
}
```

Comment: Does work in 2023 with Safari anymore

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
select {
    background: #fff;
    color: #2dccd3;
    outline: #ffffff solid thick;
    outline-offset: -5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Does work in 2023 with Safari anymore

Answer (score -3):

Just use

```
border: 1px ridge rgb(169, 169, 169);
```

border radius will be `0px`

solution is in changing the border-style to `ridge`.

be happy