# Select Box Border Difference Between Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a select box which have a CSS property:

```
border: 1px;
```

This works well at Chrome but I have a problem with Safari. It is not fit to its container:

[image]

When I set CSS to:

```
border: 0px;
```

Problem is fixed:

[image]

However when border is set to 0 border totally disappears at Chrome.

How can I fix that problem? (setting that property only for Safari or any other ways).

Comment: [This website](http://browserhacks.com) might help you add some safari-specific styles? Fixing the issue would be preferable, but if all else fails...

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283461/remove-default-round-border-of-select-element-in-mac-os-browserchrome) shows how you can target different browsers:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 0;  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */    
-moz-border-radius: 0;  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */     
border-radius: 0;  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
```